# Weird scrolling behaviour when using Tab Controller - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I am building an iOS app using Swift. In my app, I am using a paging menu controller (called PageMenu) built from other view controllers placed inside a scroll view ([you can view it on GitHub here](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu)). It is similar to how Instagram looks:

[image: PageMenu example screenshot]

When I set up the PageMenu in my project, it looks and works great...

BUT, when I embed the view within a Tab Bar Controller to add in a normal iOS Tab Bar, the scrolling within the PageMenu view doesn't work...and I get weird diagonal scrolling, and I can't actually scroll down if there is more content.

**Does anyone have any idea of why this might be happening and how to fix it?**

[image: Diagonal scrolling]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure that you set up the frame size when you are initializing the page menu.

If your scroll view is bigger than the actual view, then you will only be able to scroll the view, and not scroll the content inside it properly.

Set up the frame size of view while embedding. Check the parent view frame size.

Comment: Thanks @sumitMagdum, I personally didn't change the frame size, but I remembered that I had a similar issue when the top navigation bar was set to translucent. Setting it to page fixed it in that situation, and so I switched my tab bar to opaque as well and now it is fixed!

Comment: can you explain how you fix your problem?. i'm having same problem.

Comment: First check parent view frame using view.parentview()